# SQL Query COUNT(Distinct

Tags: sql-server, count

I'm using SQL and am having trouble finding the correct syntax to run a specific query. I'm trying to look into a large amount of data which is why I need to make sure I get this right.

My table looks like the below.

Table1

```
Column 1 . Column 2
1234     . A
1245     . B
1234     . A
1256     . C
1234     . A
```

I want to be able to write a simple query that only gives me those in Column 1 that appear more than two times but still have their same values rather than replacing it with a different number (actual amounts will vary but this is the easiest).

I was thinking of using a Count(Distinct but I haven't been able to get it working. Any ideas?

Comment: so what have you tried?

Comment: What are the expected results for that example data

Comment: tell us a bit more about the database that you use, mysql , mssql ,oracle , mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what "still have their same values rather than replacing it with a different number" means, but perhaps this SQL is what you need:

```
select *
from Table1
where Column1 in (
  select Column1
  from Table1
  group by Column1 
  having count(*) > 2
  );
```

Here it is working in a fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4b443/1

Answer (score 0):

this will work for sure

```
select column1, column2 from table where column1 in ( select column1 
                    from table1 
                    group by column1
                    having count(column1) >=2 )
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly:

```
select column1
from table t
group by column 1
having count(*) > 2 and
       min(column2) = max(column2);
```

This gets values from `column1` that appear more than two times, but where all the rows have the same value for `column2`.